# About subcategory of parabolic Category $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, weights

It follows from Exercise 1.13 in Humphreys' Category $\mathcal{O}$ book that $M\in\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_{\chi_\lambda}$ has a direct sum decomposition $M=\oplus M_i$ such that all weights of each $M_i$ are contained in a single coset of root lattice $\Lambda_r$ in $\mathfrak{h}^*$. Then, the category $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_{\chi_\lambda}$ decomposes as a direct sum of full subcategories, which can be indexed by the nonempty intersection of the orbit $W\cdot\lambda$ with the cosets $\mathfrak{h}^*/\Lambda_r$. From now on, we use the anti-dominant weight $\mu$ in the intersection to parameterize the corresponding subcategory of $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_{\chi_\lambda}$. We denote this subcategories by $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_{\mu}$. In particular, if $I=\emptyset$, then the parabolic subalgebra $\mathfrak{p}$ collapses to a Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_{\mu}$ turns into the ordinary block $\mathcal{O}_{\mu}$ of the BGG category $\mathcal{O}$.

I would like to know whether $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_{\mu}=\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_{\chi_\mu}$ for $\mu$ being regular integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{O}_\chi^{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a full subcategory of $\mathcal{O}_\chi$, so the answer is yes. That is:

- $\mathcal{O}_\mu = \mathcal{O}_{\chi_\mu}$, for all $\mu$
- $\mathcal{O}_\mu^{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the full subcategory of $\mathcal{O}_\mu$ of locally $\mathfrak{l}$-finite modules.
- $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\mu}^{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the full subcategory of $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\mu}$ of locally $\mathfrak{l}$-finite modules.

Hence $\mathcal{O}_\mu^{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathcal{O}_{\chi_\mu}^{\mathfrak{p}}$ for all $\mu$.

Comment: I think the right argument requires the fact that $\mu$ is integral.

Comment: Actually, reading the question again I don't think I understand it. Using your notation, the $\mu$ in $\mathcal{O}_\mu^{\mathfrak{p}}$ is required to be anti-dominant, you define it as such. How is $\mathcal{O}_\mu^{\mathfrak{p}}$ different from $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\mu}^{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\mu}^\mathfrak{p}$ can be decomposed into direct sum of full.subcategories, which can be indexed by the nonempty intersection of the orbit $W\cdot\mu $ with the cosets $\mathfrak{h}^*/\Lambda_r$. While $\mathcal{O}_{\mu}^\mathfrak{p}$ is just one direct summand of direct sum of full.subcategories. I would like to know whether the direct sum of full.subcategories is just trivial direct sum when $\mu$ is integral.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Humphreys discusses this in Section 9.15.